# How to copy resource to src target directory with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, resources, copy

I'm currently working on an existing project which has a pom.xml file with the following:

```xml
<resources>
    <resource>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

I have in the base path a directory called properties which contains properties files. I want to copy when packaging all the properties files contains under properties/ in my src directory (otherwise the program will crash due to missing configuration files).

So my question is:

How can i, with Maven include resource files that are not located under src directory?

I try this one but it doesn't seem to work:

```xml
<resources>
    <resource>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.properties</include>
            <include>../properties/**</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If your file structure is like this:
[Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

[image]

Then you dont have to add the resources elemt. 
Maven copies by **default** all the files and folders that are located in your /src/main/resources folder to your build folder and locates them in the root of your compiled classpath files.
if you have for example a file called **configuration.properties** located in `/src/main/resources/configuration.properties` then when running `mvn clean compile` this file will be copied to your `/target/classes/configuration.properties`
So if you remove that part the files will be located where u want them

```
<resource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*.properties</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
```

Comment: thanks for answering that fast, the problem is the project is quite old (prior to maven) so it doesn't follow the maven standard directory layout. Your answer was very useful, i just had to add my properties directory as resource directory.

Comment: No. Best is to change the folder structure and follow the conventions which makes your life easier.

Comment: Glad I could help. As khmarbaise it makes your life easier to follow the standard convetion. Makes life easier for you and every1 else that uses this project :)

Comment: I'm new into the development team so the decision to change the project structure is not up to me. I would like to change the project structure (it will avoid me tricky problem like this one) but i can't. Thx for your help you save me a lot of time ;-).

Comment: I hate this when the answer basically convinces OP to change his ways, then gets accepted. Believe it or not, I came here looking for a way to do what OP originally intended to do. This accepted answer does **not** answer the actual question.

Answer (score 19):

By migrating of projects from ant to maven without changing project structure set your sourceDirectory testSourceDirectory in the build and use the maven-resource-plugin as folowing take care in wich phase you execute the goals.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources01</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources02</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/build/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/target/</directory>
                                <include>*.jar</include>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thx for replying, i would give it a try if zpontikas didn't give me a solution.

Comment: so what is happening here:

1.execution with the id copy resources01 copying all *.property files finding in the ${basedir}/src copying in the directory ${basedir}/target/classes in the same package as in the src they are.

2.execution with the id copy resources02 will put the result *.jar file in the ${basedir}/build/lib , this was where the ant project allready put the result previouse.

I know a bit hardt, finaly you need to delete by the mvn clean the build/lib.
Command: mvn install you shoud use

Answer (score 5):

To copy everything from source to destination, I used following

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static/</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/gui/build/</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```