# How to include additional properties file in same relative location of springboot jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have Spring boot application with following structure

```
src/main/java/com/test/App.java
    |           |
    |           |__/sub1
    |           |       |
    |           |       |__Config/custom.properties
    |           |
    |           |__/sub2
    |                   |
    |                   |__Config/custom.properties
    |
    |
    |___resources/application.properties
```

How to Configure POM file so that springboot plugin or maven resources plugin will copy both custom.properties into similar relative path in the generated jar file. Can it be made generic, i.e i can add any additional sub* folders, and maven would pickup without additional changes in pom file

Comment: do you want to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289098/how-to-copy-resource-to-src-target-directory-with-maven

Comment: Thanks a lot clevertension, The link helped, now i can see my properties files packaged inside the jar correctly.