# Intellij - Not able to read a file from other package in the same module

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Idea - 2021.3.2 and Java 8. In Intellij, I am not able to read a file in another package in the same module. The file is under main and not resource folder. But in Eclipse, I am able to read.

For example. Below code prints different outputs in both eclipse and intellij.

```
    import java.net.URL;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL resource = TestMain.class.getResource("/org/files/input.txt");
        if(resource == null) {
            System.out.println("Resource is null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Resource found!!");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Image attached]

In Intellij, the code prints "Resource is null", but in eclipse, the code prints "Resource found!!".

Is there any setting I need to enable/disable in intellij ? Why code is behaving different in Intellij Idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the file into resources/org/files.

.txt files are not copied to classpath from the source roots by Maven conventions.

If you want to copy these files from the source roots, you need to adjust pom.xml configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23289401/104891.

Eclipse is not following the conventions and you will get different results in command line Maven and in the IDE, which is bad.